# Pyspark: Multi-threaded Jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I am having some problems with running multiple threads using a single SparkContext `sc`. I create a pool of threads and then each thread loads some data from the same table but using different rows. Each thread processes the loaded data under a dataframe and applies several transformations.

The current issue that I have is when I apply a transformation. For example I have a dataframe in the thread and then I apply a transformation like `StringIndexer(inputCol="category", "indexed").fit(df).transform(df)`. However, during the execution of those threads eventually I will receive an `IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Output column indexed already exists.` The weird thing about it is that if I turn the pool size to 1, then everything runs as it's supposed to. But, If I decide to increase the number of threads then it fails. It looks like the same dataframe is used on some of the threads. I have no idea why this is happening, I am not sharing any variables or anything between those threads (well only the  `SparkContext`).

For creating the threads I use the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

```
def processModels(sc, table, models):
  for model in models:
    # Load the data coressponding to that model.
    query = "select * from %s where model=%d" % (table, model)
    df = sqlContext.sql(query)
    df = df.fillna(0).fillna("None").cache()

    # Apply some transformations to the dataset.        
    stages = []
    dtypes = df.dtypes 
    for dtype in dtypes:
        column_name = dtype[0]
        column_type = dtype[1]
        if(column_type=="string"):
            indexerModel = StringIndexer(inputCol=column_name, outputCol="%s_cat"%column_name).fit(df)
            if(len(indexerModel.labels)>1):
                stages.append(indexerModel.copy())
    pipeline = PipelineModel(stages=stages)
    df = pipeline.transform(df)
    print("Model %d has %d samples." % (model, df.count()))
```

Comment: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: I've added some of the code that  causes the problem. Do you see anything suspicious?

Comment: may I ask why you are doing that ?

Comment: You mean using multiple threads? It really helps to reduce the execution time.

Comment: It is still neither Minimal nor Reproducible. And if error message you shown is the actually output then there is no way you get this from this piece of code.

Comment: It turns out the problem is not code-related. The settings for running it using spark-submit affect the rate at which I get the error. Is it likely that  there are some  concurrency issues because of the parallel use of the same SparkContext? What would you suggest to look out for when using the same spark context in multiple threads? Thanks.